# Display graph without saving using pydot

Tags: python, pydot

I am trying to display a simple graph using pydot.

My question is that is there any way to display the graph without writing it to a file as currently I use write function to first draw and then have to use the Image module to show the files.

However is there any way that the graph directly gets printed on the screen without being saved ??

---

Also as an update I would like to ask in this same question that I observe that while the image gets saved very quickly when I use the show command of the Image module it takes noticeable time for the image to be seen .... Also sometimes I get the error that the image could'nt be opened because it was either deleted or saved in unavailable location which is not correct as I am saving it at my Desktop..... Does anyone know what's happening and is there a faster way to get the image loaded.....

Thanks a lot....

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379448/plotting-directed-graphs-in-python-in-a-way-that-show-all-edges-separately/17823100#17823100

Comment: related but applied to pygraphviz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608316/capture-pygraphviz-image-rendering-without-saving-to-a-file/18610140#comment119200221_18610140 I'd love to know how to do it in pygraphviz too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid `pydot` uses `graphviz` to render the graphs. I.e., it runs the executable and loads the resulting image.

Bottom line - no, you cannot avoid creating the file.

Comment: johntex provided a solution

Comment: check out my solution.  it's simple and avoids creating a file :)

Comment: While being technically correct, the answer is not helpful. You do have to create the file, but you don't have to write to disk. See other answers to this question..

Answer (score 34):

Here's a simple solution using IPython:

```
from IPython.display import Image, display

def view_pydot(pdot):
    plt = Image(pdot.create_png())
    display(plt)
```

Example usage:

```
import networkx as nx
to_pdot = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot
pdot = to_pdot(nx.complete_graph(5))
view_pydot(pdot)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Exactly what I needed: To just immediately display the graph with as few lines as possible with the console (e.g. spyder)

Answer (score 30):

You can render the image from `pydot` by calling `GraphViz`'s `dot` without writing any files to the disk. Then just plot it. This can be done as follows:

```py
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import networkx as nx

# create a `networkx` graph
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2])
g.add_edge(1, 2)

# convert from `networkx` to a `pydot` graph
pydot_graph = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(g)

# render the `pydot` by calling `dot`, no file saved to disk
png_str = pydot_graph.create_png(prog='dot')

# treat the DOT output as an image file
sio = io.BytesIO()
sio.write(png_str)
sio.seek(0)
img = mpimg.imread(sio)

# plot the image
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, aspect='equal')
plt.show()
```

This is particularly useful for directed graphs.

See also this [pull request](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/812), which introduces such capabilities directly to `networkx`.

Comment: Just as a quick addendum, if you're in a notebook you can render `png_str` (bytes) directly using `Image(png_str)` (from `IPython.display`).

Comment: Made some minor adjustments in this adaptation: https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/d74ecbd4fdfdaa115bf28b2db15c7e296553435d/python/matplotlib/graphviz.py#L9
Thanks for posting this code! (Ended up just using `pydot`, as that was able to handle the graph of interest in this case.)

Comment: @EricCousineau By the statement `g = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_text)` it appears that you are using an older `pydot` version. Please note that as of `pydot == 1.2.3`, the function `graph_from_dot_data` returns a `list` in all cases (in previous versions it returned a graph when singleton). See also [this comment](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/159#issuecomment-334799706), and https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/pydot.py#L235, https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/dot_parser.py#L545.

Comment: Ah, thank you! (Updated: https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/51e8020/python/matplotlib/graphviz.py#L9 )

Comment: Is there a way to also preserve edge labels within the image?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160103/288875) (how to show images in python), here's a few lines:

```
gr = ... <pydot.Dot instance> ...

import tempfile, Image
fout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
gr.write(fout.name,format="png")
Image.open(fout.name).show()
```

`Image` is from the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Comment: As of March 2019, Python Imaging Library is mostly replaced by [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

[IPython.display.SVG](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.SVG) method embeds an SVG into the display and can be used to display graph without saving to a file.

Here, [keras.utils.model_to_dot](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/#modeltodot-function) is used to convert a Keras model to dot format.

```
from IPython.display import SVG
from tensorflow import keras

#Create a keras model.
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2,1), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))

#model visualization
SVG(keras.utils.model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me inside a Python 3 shell (requires the [`Pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) package):

```py
import pydot
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type="digraph")
node = pydot.Node("Hello pydot!")
graph.add_node(node)

Image.open(BytesIO(graph.create_png())).show()
```

You can also add a method called `_repr_html_` to an object with a pydot `graph` member to render a nice crisp SVG inside a Jupyter notebook:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return self.graph.create_svg().decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well with `AGraph Class` as well

https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/agraph.html#pygraphviz.AGraph.draw

> If path is None, the result is returned as a Bytes object.

So, just omit this argument to return the image data without saving it to disk

Using

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout, to_agraph
g = nx.Graph()
...
A = to_agraph(g)
A.draw()
```

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph

In order to show the resulting image which is saved as Bytes object:

```
# create image without saving to disk
img = A.draw(format='png')
image = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
image.show(title="Graph")
```

it needs

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
```

Comment: for me this doesn't put out a window with a picture of the graph...

Comment: Now I expanded my answer and included a code snippet to show the graph.
The `img` is the resulting "Bytes object" that can be displayed or otherwise processed.
In this example I demonstrate how to display it without saving to disk