# python gv vs pygrsphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

python noob here.

I am trying to figure out which module has a lesser learning curve. the gv module which comes as a language bindings with graphviz or pygraphviz.

does pygraphviz internally use gv warranting me to install both?

http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gv.3python.pdf

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I liked [`pydot`](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) and then used the output to either pipe it into graphviz (dot) or used the builtin spawn methods.  It had a simpler interface in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.io/) which is a widely accepted graph package in Python, together with its `pydot` or `matplotlib` interfaces, in particular the inline drawing capabilities. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596962/display-graph-without-saving-using-pydot/18522941#18522941).